# Component XML duplicated

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa

I'm working with DXA on Tridion 2013 SP1 and I'm trying to edit the `language` element in the `Localization Configuration` component with the `General Configuration` schema. Upon changing the language from English to French and switching over to the Source tab, the XML code is duplicated. When removing the duplicated XML code, I am able to save successfully, otherwise I get a standard XML validation error because there are duplicate elements.

I have also tried changing elements in other components with the same schema, which yields the same result. I tried disabling all even system code and GUI extensions with no luck. This duplicated code only seems to occur when the component has been localized.

[image]

Yields:

```
<GeneralConfiguration xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core">
    <name>Localization Configuration</name>
    <settings>
        <name>culture</name>
        <value>en-US</value>
    </settings>
    <settings>
        <name>language</name>
        <value>English</value>
    </settings>
</GeneralConfiguration>
```

[image]

Yields:

```
<GeneralConfiguration xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core">
    <name xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core">Localization Configuration</name>
    <settings xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core">
        <name>culture</name>
        <value>en-US</value>
    </settings>
    <settings xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core">
        <name xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core">language</name>
        <value>French</value>
    </settings>
    <name xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core">Localization Configuration</name>
    <settings xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core">
        <name>culture</name>
        <value>en-US</value>
    </settings>
    <settings xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core">
        <name xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core">language</name>
        <value>French</value>
   </settings>
</GeneralConfiguration>
```

Has anyone seen this before or have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: This looks like a glitch with the browser, some custom GUI extension or a defect with the CM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up just needing to clear my cache and cookies and restart the browser. Worked like a charm